# Find and replace in a block of code with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="group-sizing">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <h3>Guest <span>1</span> Welcome</h3>
            <div>
                <select id="level1"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this function:

```
var guestBlock = $(".group-sizing").html();
$("#guestNum").change(function(){
    var count = $(this).val();
    $(".group-sizing .form-group:gt("+(count-1)+")").remove();
    for (var i = $(".group-sizing .form-group").length; i < count; i++){
        $(guestBlock).find(?????????).html(i); //find and change span and id of select
        $(".group-sizing").append(guestBlock); //then print the block
    };
});
```

In `$(guestBlock).find()` I want to find the span from the `<h3>` and the id from the `<select>`. Then increment them by i but so far I haven't been able to get it. It always prints with 1 in those spaces.

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: Let me be an ass here, `?????????` is not a valid selector -- so what selectors have you tried?

Comment: what calls this: `$("#guestNum").change(function(){`

Comment: `<select id="guestNum">` is a select earlier in the HTML. That calls the change function.

Comment: Output expected is the entire block but with `<h3>Guest <span>2</span> Welcome</h3>` and `<select id="level2">` and so on according to the for statement.

Comment: The last trial was `$(guestBlock).find('span').html(i);` to test for changing the span and then move on to figuring out the select id. But that still prints 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cloning to solve it like

```js
var $guestBlock = $(".group-sizing > .form-group").first().clone();
$("#guestNum").change(function() {
  var count = $(this).val();
  var $groups = $(".group-sizing > .form-group");
  $groups.slice(count).remove();
  for (var i = $groups.length; i < count; i++) {
    var $clone = $guestBlock.clone().appendTo('.group-sizing');
    $clone.find('h3 span').text(i + 1);
    $clone.find('select').attr('id', 'level' + (i + 1));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-sizing">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <h3>Guest <span>1</span> Welcome</h3>
      <div>
        <select id="level1"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<select id="guestNum">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```